# How to load datas not in realtime in firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following problem to solve:

[image]

All datas are loaded in realtime (this time even multiple times per post), but I just want to refresh with a refresher I already have.

This is my refresher:

```
// Refresher
func refresh() {
    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Aktualisieren")
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DiscoveryViewController.refreshData) , for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
    tableView.addSubview(refresher)
}

@objc func refreshData(sender: Any) {
    loadTopPosts()
    refresher.endRefreshing()
}
```

And with this I load all posts:

```
func loadTopPosts() {
    ProgressHUD.show("Lade...", interaction: false)
    self.postArray.removeAll()
    self.tableView.reloadData()

    // Aktuelle Location des aktuell eingeloggten Users laden
    guard let currentUserUid = UserApi.shared.CURRENT_USER_ID else { return }
    let databaseRef = LocationApi.shared.geoRef
    databaseRef.getLocationForKey(currentUserUid) { (location, error) in
        if error != nil {
            ProgressHUD.showError("Posts konnten nicht geladen werden")
        } else if location != nil {
            print("Location for \(currentUserUid) is [\(location!.coordinate.latitude), \(location!.coordinate.longitude)]")

            // Alle Posts im vorgegebenen Umkreis laden
            let REF_GEO_POSTS = Database.database().reference().child("geolocation_posts")
            let geoRef = GeoFire(firebaseRef: REF_GEO_POSTS)
            // Lade den aktuell eingestellten Radius aus der Datenbank
            self.observeRadius(completion: { (radius) in
                let currentRadius = radius
            // Üperprüfe, welche Posts im Umkreis erstellt wurden
                let circleQuery = geoRef.query(at: location!, withRadius: Double(currentRadius)!)

            circleQuery.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (postIds, location) in

                self.observePost(withPostId: postIds, completion: { (posts) in
                    guard let userUid = posts.uid else { return }
                    self.observeUser(uid: userUid, completion: { (users) in
                        let postArray = UserPostModel(post: posts, user: users)
                        self.postArray.append(postArray)
                        self.postArray.sort(by: {$0.post!.secondsFrom1970! > $1.post!.secondsFrom1970!})
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
                        ProgressHUD.dismiss()

                    })
                })

                })
            })
            if self.postArray.count == 0 {
                ProgressHUD.dismiss()
            }
        } else {
            ProgressHUD.showError("Posts konnten nicht geladen werden")
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the functions where I over serve datas from firebase:

```
let REF_POSTS = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
func observePost(withPostId id: String, completion: @escaping (PostModel) -> Void) {
    REF_POSTS.child(id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
        let newPost = PostModel(dictionary: dic, key: snapshot.key)
        completion(newPost)
    }
}

let REF_USERS = Database.database().reference().child("users")
func observeUser(uid: String, completion: @escaping (UserModel) -> Void) {
    REF_USERS.child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let dic = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
        let newUser = UserModel(dictionary: dic)
        completion(newUser)
    }
}

func observeRadius(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    guard let currentUserUid = UserApi.shared.CURRENT_USER_ID else { return }
    let REF_RADIUS = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUserUid).child("radius")
    REF_RADIUS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (radius) in
        let currentRadius = radius.value as? String
        completion(currentRadius!)
    }
}
```

What I now want to do is to disable the realtime function (updating the tableView only if I refresh). So if I refresh, everything will be displayed correctly.

How to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: So you want to use a RT database not in RT ?

Comment: if this is possible yes. If I have a user being online and multiple shares at once, the tableview will be updated with every share. Thats not what the users want to see. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is `observe`, that keeps notifying every time an update happens in the database. And there is `observeSingleEvent`, that will only provide you data when requested.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

And also, your geofire reference will keep notifying you for every update, if you don't want it to do that, remove it like this:

"If you're not interested in getting updates on new/moving users after the initial query, this is also a great moment to remove your observer by calling `removeObserverWithFirebaseHandle` or `removeAllObservers`."

in your case it's posts, and that was mentioned here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50722984/8869493

Comment: `circleQuery.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (postIds, location) in`you mean this codeline?

Comment: also, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50722753/geofire-firebase-function-is-executing-handler-multiple-times-in-swift

Comment: I already observe with `observeSingleEvent` my datas as in my edited question above.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But where do I have to call the `removeAllObservers`? For `circleQuery.observe` no `observeSingleEvent` is available.

Comment: As soon as you get data, check this: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc#waiting-for-queries-to-be-ready